# Can't find Maven artifact in Sonatype's repos

Tags: maven, sonatype

I see my published dependency here:

https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;quick~ores

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

it looks like this is the staging repo? Because when I search here:

https://search.maven.org/search?q=ores

I get no results:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

My guess is that I publishing to staging not prod when I publish the artifact, anybody know how to publish to production using Sonatype?

In my pom.xml file I have:

```
   <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

and I have:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.8</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
            <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
            <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
            <autoReleaseAfterClose>false</autoReleaseAfterClose>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

So perhaps I need to be using the production plugins instead of staging?
Seems tricky. When I set

```
<autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
```

I get this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy
>   (injected-nexus-deploy) on project async.0.1: Execution
>   injected-nexus-deploy of goal
>   org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:deploy failed:
>   403 - Forbidden -> [Help 1]

Comment: also/better look at (configuration of)/have a read on "[maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/)".. hi! :)

Comment: ..and of course good to ask: the guy/al who did that before! :)

Comment: I think this has some answers too: https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-maven-plugins

Comment: First you have to correctly login into the central repository manager (Having credentials for that) ..after you have deployed artifacts to that you have to close the staging repository (already done via plugin) and afterwards you have to release them...which means they will be synchronized to central..(which can take some time)..

Comment: how to release the artifact?